# How do i count Network cards?

Tags: linux

How do i count plugged Network cards ?

expected end result(like):

```
server0 ; 1
server1 ; 2
server2 ; 1
server3 ; 2
```

what ive tried so far:  compare strings and count them:

`# lspci -mm`

(1) some controller of these cards (even if they belog the the same card) have different output about the device name

(2) each controller have different names and recive different "pci addresses"  although they on the same card.

now I am looking for another way.(Parsing huge amounts of output will not be a problem. I take any idea that will work :)

**EDIT:** Now that my question is solved, I would like to share some more options I found on this topic.

1. comparing the bus address of the interfaces (from lspci) with dmidecode PCI and Ethernet, you can see if it is an integrated or an extra connected NIC (a problem I had: `Bus Address: 0000:3b:00.0` dmidecode doesn't give the subaddresses for each interface, but at least you can see that there is a card! )
2. `omreport chassis nics` if your server is from DELL and OMSA is configured, you can use omreport which has a good amount of details you can use.

Samples:

(1)

```
Server0 # lspci -mm | grep Eth
18:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10G X550T" -r01 "Dell" "Ethernet 10G 4P X550/I350 rNDC"
18:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10G X550T" -r01 "Dell" "Ethernet 10G 4P X550/I350 rNDC"
19:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P X550/I350 rNDC"
19:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P X550/I350 rNDC"
```

(2)

```
Server1 # lspci -mm | grep Eth
01:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
01:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
19:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
19:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
3b:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4161"
3b:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4161"


Server2 # lspci -mm | grep Eth
01:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
01:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
18:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"
18:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller" -r01 "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "Device 4160"


Server3 # lspci -mm | grep Eth
02:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 0639"
02:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 0639"
03:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 0639"
03:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 0639"
05:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X540-t Adapter"
05:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X540-t Adapter"
```

DMIDECODE:

```
Handle 0x0900, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: PCIe Slot 1
        Type: x8 PCI Express 3 x16
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Long
        ID: 1
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:05:00.0


(or)
        Current Usage: Available
```

least Samples:

```
cat test.file | grep -i "ether\|gigabit\|10G" | cut -d ":" -f 1 | uniq | wc -l  ; # -> minus 1 -> "server ; output"

ServerA ; 0
    02:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 04f8"
    02:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 04f8"

ServerB ; 1 
    02:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 04f8"
    02:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries" "NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe" "Dell" "Device 04f8"
    41:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X540-t Adapter"
    41:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X540-t Adapter"

ServerC ; 1
    18:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.2 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.3 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    65:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10G X550T" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X550-t Adapter"
    65:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller 10G X550T" -r01 "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet 10G 2P X550-t Adapter"

ServerD ; 0
    18:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.2 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
    18:00.3 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Dell" "Gigabit 4P I350-t rNDC"
```

Comment: What about : `lspci | grep -i ethernet`. You will find more methods in [this link](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-find-available-network-interfaces-on-linux/). See also [anotherlink](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-detect-whether-a-physical-cable-is-connected-to-network-card-slot-on-linux).

Comment: Oh I guess I just didn't make it clear enough, I'm looking for the physical cards in pci slots or onboard. but NOT the interfaces/ports of these cards
like server 1 got one extra network card :)

Comment: Look at my links - they contain multiple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

As you can see from your `lspci` output, each entry starts with a bus number, device number and function number (BDF). You can consider each unique bus number to be a seperate physical device.

To count them you can very easily easily cut the entry to just the bus number, remove duplicates and then count them with a combination of `cut`, `uniq` and `wc`:

```
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ lspci -mm | grep Eth                               
01:00.0 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4160
01:00.1 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 2-port Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4160
19:00.0 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller -r01 Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4160
19:00.1 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller -r01 Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4160
3b:00.0 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller -r01 Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4161
3b:00.1 Ethernet controller Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57416 NetXtreme-E Dual-Media 10G RDMA Ethernet Controller -r01 Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 4161
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ lspci -mm | grep -i "ether\|gigabit\|10G" | cut -d ":" -f 1 | uniq | wc -l
3
```

### Method 2

If you use `systemd` and [predictable interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) (which are also based on the PCIe ID), you can use the output of `ip` to get the same result:

```
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ ip link show
enp0s32f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
enp1s32f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
enp1s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
enp2s32f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
enp2s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000"
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ ip link show | grep enp | sed -E 's/.+?enp([0-9]).*/\1/' | uniq | wc -l
3
```

**excluding built in network card**

Now if you want to exclude the single built in network card (which is also connected via PCI, but directly via traces on the motherboards PCB), simply substract 1 from the result.

`bash` supports arithmetic operations, e.g. `foo=3 && echo "$((foo - 1))"`

Comment: thanks for your effort. sadly it does not work properly. this server got 2 Cards 
also your command with server0:
```2 ```

Comment: server 1: got Broadcom 57416 2 Port 10Gb Base-T + 5720 2 Port 1Gb Base-T, rNDC
 AND Broadcom BCM57416 Ethernet 10Gb 2-port BASE-T i think

Comment: @notquiterelevant Are you 100% sure about that? The BCM57416 is a dual port controller, as well as the BCM5720. One port will show up as one entry in `lspci` and you got 6 entries. That and the PCI bus ID are a 100% giveaway that the server has 3 network cards installed. Of course this would include the build-in network card.

Comment: I tried it for a while with string compare. But I found too many deviations. Now I'm just looking for something precise that also doesn't have so many exceptions :)

Comment: i am 100% sure for server 0 and 1 ; 
0 should be obvious that its the same card but still got variaions because the controller return the infos wich are slighly different (but the card uses 2 of them)- server 1 is a dell server wich a coworker prooved with looking in it and looking up the service tag ; server 2 and 3 i cant tell for 100%

Comment: **It is** 100% precise to count the devices on the PCI Bus. It seems that you want to exclude the build-in network adapter? (which is also connected via PCI  to the CPU by the way, just directly with traces on the motherboard instead of a connector) If you got one network card plugged into a PCIe connector, then your system got two network cards installed. If you got two network cards plugged into a PCIe connector, then your system got three network cards installed. Every server has at least one on-board network card.

Comment: Note that the output of my proposed solution is always exactly your expected result +1. That can be solved by substraction.

Comment: so ive tested a bit. you are right for my little sample file it was always correct ( just by +1 overall) i will run it on the whole file ; also i need some time to verify the other solutions given; ill post laster results

Comment: Ok, I tested: METHOD 2: this is a nice idea - but people have renamed their interfaces and there is no good documentation anywhere and the Docker container interfaces are also shown - it would be possible, but it is again a big effort to fix all inconsistencies because of the custom names. 
METHOD 1: there are a few inconsistencies here, but the effort to remove them is much lower than method2. but first I need to check if I can or if I am missing something again - this will take some time. but i bet there is another tool or file in linux that have better output (i stumbled over "dmidecode")

Comment: For now the solution is METHOD1 and i will mark it as the solution. but first i want to see if dmidecode can be more "exception proof" :)

Comment: @notquiterelevant From `man dmidecode`: "While this is a  good
       point in terms of report speed and safeness, this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable."

Comment: Could you elaborate on the inconsistencies of method 1?

Comment: sure , Server0 (output 3 - 1 =  2 ) but its just one card ; server1 (output 3 - 1 = 2 ) true; Server2 (output 2 -1 = 1) true; Server3 (-||-) true

Comment: my idea behind dmidecode was to check for current usage and if the slot is used, to check the bus address. (I'll post samples in under the section in the question)

Comment: @notquiterelevant interesting, I cannot reproduce that. For me the output of server0 is 2-1=1

Comment: yes this was human error. indeed Server0 was also true - was in a hurry - should have be more more precise (sorry) - i've added somthing to the samples!